# Model property concatenated from properties in different models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created entity in database using code first, which mostly refers to the dictionary tables:

```
public class Item
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Material Material { get; set; }
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public Charact Charact { get; set; }
    public int CharactId { get; set; }
    public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
    public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }
    public Size Size { get; set; }
    public int SizeId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }   
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionSum { get; set; }
}
```

All dictionary models have similar properties, where property 'No' is key property in this case and is one or two character string:

```
public class Size
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string No { get; set; }
}
```

While creating new Item, user will select one record from each all avaliable in dictionary tables and save them in the Item table:

ItemsController for Create:

```
// GET: Items/Create
public IActionResult Create(int? gr)
{
    ViewData["CharactId"] = new SelectList(_context.Charact, "Id", "Name");
    ViewData["GroupId"] = new SelectList(_context.Group, "Id", "Name");
    ViewData["ItemTypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.ItemType.Where(ItemType => ItemType.GroupId == gr), "Id", "Name");
    ViewData["MaterialId"] = new SelectList(_context.Materials, "Id", "Name");
    ViewData["SizeId"] = new SelectList(_context.Size, "Id", "Name");
    ViewData["SupplierId"] = new SelectList(_context.Supplier.Where(Supplier => Supplier.GroupId == gr), "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Description,MaterialId,SupplierId,CharactId,ItemTypeId,SizeId,GroupId,Number,DescriptionSum")] Item item)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(item);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    ViewData["CharactId"] = new SelectList(_context.Charact, "Id", "Name", item.CharactId);
    ViewData["GroupId"] = new SelectList(_context.Group, "Id", "Name", item.GroupId);
    ViewData["ItemTypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.ItemType, "Id", "Name", item.ItemTypeId);
    ViewData["MaterialId"] = new SelectList(_context.Materials, "Id", "Name", item.MaterialId);
    ViewData["SizeId"] = new SelectList(_context.Size, "Id", "Name", item.SizeId);
    ViewData["SupplierId"] = new SelectList(_context.Supplier, "Id", "Name", item.SupplierId);
    return View(item);
}
```

What I am trying to do is to "automatically" populate Number property, accordingly to selected in form options, based on 'No' properties and save it in database:

```
Number = Group.No + Supplier.No + ItemType.No + Charact.No + Material.No + Size.No;
```

Concatenated number would define chosen configuration of options. Because the same "No" can occure multiple times in the same table, it cannot be used as identification column.

---

I have tried few approaches, which I found in web:

Updating ItemController:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult>Create([Bind("Id,Name,Description,MaterialId,SupplierId,CharactId,ItemTypeId,SizeId,GroupId,Number,DescriptionSum")] Item item)
{            
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        item.Number = item.Group.No + item.Supplier.No + item.ItemType.No + item.Charact.No + item.Material.No + item.Size.No;
        _context.Add(item);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
ViewData["CharactId"] = new SelectList(_context.Charact, "Id", "Name", item.CharactId);
ViewData["GroupId"] = new SelectList(_context.Group, "Id", "Name", item.GroupId);
ViewData["ItemTypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.ItemType, "Id", "Name", item.ItemTypeId);
ViewData["MaterialId"] = new SelectList(_context.Materials, "Id", "Name", item.MaterialId);
ViewData["SizeId"] = new SelectList(_context.Size, "Id", "Name", item.SizeId);
ViewData["SupplierId"] = new SelectList(_context.Supplier, "Id", "Name", item.SupplierId);
return View(item);
}
```

Exception occurred:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   `Database.Controllers.ItemsController.Create(Item item)` in ItemsController.cs
>
> `item.Number = item.Group.No + item.Supplier.No + item.ItemType.No + item.Charact.No + item.Material.No + item.Size.No;`

Changed model:

```
public class Item
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Material Material { get; set; }
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public Charact Charact { get; set; }
    public int CharactId { get; set; }
    public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
    public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }
    public Size Size { get; set; }
    public int SizeId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }   
    public string Number 
    { get
                           { 
                   return this.Number = this.Group.No + this.Supplier.No + this.ItemType.No + this.Charact.No + this.Material.No + this.Size.No; 
               } 
               private set { }
             }
    public string DescriptionSum { get; set; }
}
```

Same Exception but concerning line

```
public string Number { get { return this.Number = this.Group.No + this.Supplier.No + this.ItemType.No + this.Charact.No + this.Material.No + this.Size.No; } private set { } }
```

in Item model.

Other model change:

```
public class Item
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Material Material { get; set; }
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public Charact Charact { get; set; }
    public int CharactId { get; set; }
    public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
    public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }
    public Size Size { get; set; }
    public int SizeId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    private string _value;
    public string Number { get { return _value; } private set {_value = this.Group.No + this.Supplier.No + this.ItemType.No + this.Charact.No + this.Material.No + this.Size.No; } }
    public string DescriptionSum { get; set; }       
}
```

still same exception in line:

```
public string Number { get { return _value; } private set {_value = this.Group.No + this.Supplier.No + this.ItemType.No + this.Charact.No + this.Material.No + this.Size.No; } }
```

I couldn't find any other solutions. Please help.

BR

Comment: Navigation properties are null, you need to create instances before to use them

Comment: When you create instance of Item class The material class & The Charact is class null. So when you try to access the property Number it will throw object reference

Comment: `public string Number { get { return _value; } private set {_value = this.Group?.No + this.Supplier?.No + this.ItemType?.No + this.Charact?.No + this.Material?.No + this.Size?.No; } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create instance of `Item class`; The `material` class & The `Charact` is class null. So when you try to access the `Number` it will throw object reference as Navigation Properties are null.

**Option 1** Check Null and Assign the variable.

```
public string Number 
{ 
  get { return _value; } 
  private set {_value = this.Group?.No + this.Supplier?.No + this.ItemType?.No + 
   this.Charact?.No + this.Material?.No + this.Size?.No; } 
}
```

If your using C# 6 or greater you can use this [Null-Conditional Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

**Option 2** Fill the Navigation object with data.

```
public class Item
{
  //YourProperties Here

  public Item()
  {
     this.Material = new Material();
     this.Charact = new Charact();
  }
}
```

Basically you need to data to assign data to navigation property then it would work with your same code.